# Bootstrap popover not creating when tabing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a form with several inputs and when I click on each field it correctly fires the focus method I have linked up with jQuery (I checked by console logging) however it only launches the popover when I actually click the field and does not work when I tab between them (it still calls the function, but the popover never appears).

Here is some example code:

```
// create the popover on focus but does not work when tabbing
$(".tblData").focus(function(){
    $(this).popover({content: "Info!", position: "right"});
}
});
// destroy the popover on blur to be efficient
$(".tblData").blur(function(){
    $(this).popover('destroy');
});
```

Comment: Added, sorry I did not have the privileges to do so before.

Comment: No problem! Just thought I'd add a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add an attribute and call show when creating the popover like so:

```
$(this).popover({content: "Info!", position: "right", trigger: "manual"}).popover('show');
```

This is needed to tell the attribute that you will control showing and hiding, and that you will always show it.